# Installing docker, getting: `PreDepends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~) but 1.51 is to be installed`

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation, docker

So these are the [install instructions for Docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/)

After you [setup the GPG key and prerequisites](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository) it basically consists of:

1. Getting the (latest) `.deb` release from the [releases page](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/release-notes/)
2. `sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb`

I was getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'docker-desktop' instead of './docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 docker-desktop : PreDepends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~) but 1.51 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But if I tried `sudo apt upgrade init-system-helpers` then I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
init-system-helpers is already the newest version (1.51).
```

What is the solution to this, to install Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing a more recent version of `init-system-helpers` manually may work for private installations or serve as an ad-hoc workaround, a more stable solutions seems to be an upgrade of the Ubuntu Version to at least Focal and hope that the docker people are not raising the dependency again so soon.

That may be difficult for a variety of other reasons as well, but the key insight here seems to be that Docker - although otherwise stated in their documentation - does **not** support Bionic (at least `docker-desktop` does not, things may be different for other parts of docker).

Comment: In other words, Docker Desktop is not enterprise ready for Ununtu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 21):

After some googling around, [this solution](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/60574#issuecomment-881696291) proved useful:

1. `wget http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/init-system-helpers/init-system-helpers_1.60_all.deb`
2. `sudo apt install ./init-system-helpers_1.60_all.deb`
3. And finally `sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb`

Comment: imho this is not a solution. A solution would be if the maintainers of docker do their job correctly and, if they state that Ubuntu 18 LTS is still supported, build a package, that actually depends on the latest _provided_ version of that LTS version they are pretending to support. Installing a newer version manually is just a workaround and in enterprise environments it's not even possible in most cases.

Comment: @UniversE  Yeah, you're right.  Much better to say, "Well, that's up the Docker boys", and just sit there in a sense of failure until someone else fixes it, because you know, this is "not a solution".

Comment: @UniversE  PS. Definition of "solution": 
/səˈluːʃ(ə)n/   noun

a means of solving a problem or dealing with a difficult situation.

Comment: okay, since you are good with dictionaries, try looking up the word "workaround"

Comment: @UniversE  OK, let me try to make my point another way:  What exactly is your criticism?  Are you saying I should take down my posted solution?  In other words, what is the point of your point?

Comment: I posted an alternate answer to make my point clearer. Don't get me wrong: I am not here to bash. I'm just concerned that the workaround you provided is maybe not so suitable for other people who come across this thread via googling the problem e.g.

Comment: @UniversE  I'm tracking. Thank you. Apologies for being sensitive

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Comment: I wonder if moving this package version forward has the potential side effect of breaking other packages on 18.04 LTS?